# If a menu item has parent pages it is not shown as clickable link

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, xhtml

I have a dropdown menu. In this menu if there are parent pages, the first link becomes non-clickable. It is supposed to act as a link. 
Check the page

> http://www.deletedurl.com/wp/

As you can see when you are on About Us page it is non-clickable. 
What is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the sub menu ul becomes visible, it is placed on top of the parent li and thats why it became non-clikcable. Modify the style.css as below and it should work fine.

Style.css (line 67)

```
#navigation ul {
   padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Style.css (line 170)

```
#navigation ul li ul {
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]